# Sum untill condition For all (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sum holidays with following non holiday day. Then drop the holidays.
How can i do that?

My pandas dataframe df ;

```
Date        Holiday   Value
01.01.2022     0       4
02.01.2022     1       0.5
03.01.2022     1       0.1
04.01.2022     0       0.2
05.01.2022     0       0.2
06.01.2022     0       0.4
07.01.2022     0       5
08.01.2022     1       0.3
09.01.2022     0       5
```

I want to see ;

```
Date        Holiday   Value
01.01.2022     0       4
04.01.2022     0       0.8 
05.01.2022     0       0.2
06.01.2022     0       0.4
07.01.2022     0       5
09.01.2022     0       5.3
```

Sum all the 1 (by order) then write to following 0

*04.01.2022 -> 0.5 + 0.1 + 0.2*

How can do that with pandas?

Answer (score 2):

We can do `cumsum` with `groupby`

```
key = df['Holiday'].eq(0).iloc[::-1].cumsum()

out = df.groupby(key).agg({'Date':'last','Value':'sum'}).iloc[::-1]
#out['holiday'] = 0
```

Comment: great minds... ;)

Comment: @user3483203 right :-)

Answer (score 2):

you can compute groups ending on 0, then aggregate by last or sum:

```
group = df['Holiday'].rsub(1)[::-1].cumsum()
out = (df.groupby(group, sort=False, as_index=False)
         .agg({'Date': 'last', 'Holiday': 'last', 'Value': 'sum'})
       )
```

output:

```
         Date  Holiday  Value
0  01.01.2022        0    4.0
1  04.01.2022        0    0.8
2  05.01.2022        0    0.2
3  06.01.2022        0    0.4
4  07.01.2022        0    5.0
5  09.01.2022        0    5.3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through the dataframe using a counter and then keeping only the 0 rows

try:

```
counter = 0
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
   if row['Holiday'] == 1:
      counter += row['Value']
   else:
      df['Value'][idx] += counter
      counter = 0

df = df.loc[df['Holiday'] == 0]
```